# Show $E(\frac{1}{2\theta\sum_{i = 1}^n W_i}) = \frac{1}{2(n-1)}$ given the pdf $f(y\mid\theta) = \theta y^{\theta - 1}$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n$ be a random sample from the pdf $$f(y\mid\theta) = \theta y^{\theta - 1}, 0 < y < 1, \theta > 0 .$$
show that $$E\left(\frac{1}{2\theta\sum_{i = 1}^n W_i}\right) = \frac{1}{2(n-1)}$$

I have showed that $\sum_{i = 1}^n -\ln(Y_i)$ is sufficient for $\theta$, and if $W_i = -\ln(Y_i)$, I have showed that $W_i$ has an exponential distribution with mean $1/\theta$. I have also showed that $2\theta \sum_{i=1}^n W_i $ has a $\chi^2$ distribution with $2n$ degrees of freedom.

My first question can we treat $2\theta\sum_{i=1}^n W_i$ as just 1/y? If so, I got to the following step $$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{y} f(y) dy = \frac{1}{\Gamma(n)} \frac{1}{2} \int _0^\infty u^{n-2} e^{-u} du$$... I am wondering how to solve $\int _0^\infty u^{n-2} e^{-u} du?$ I know it is going to be $\Gamma(n-1)$ but what is the process for finding it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing in your first question, you wonder if you are allowed to divide by $Y=2\theta\sum_{i=1}^n W_i$ even though $Y$ might be zero.

The answer is yes, because $Y\ge0$ almost surely, hence $E\left(\frac{1}{Y}\right)$ is well-defined although it has no reason to be finite at this point.

If it bothers you to divide by zero, you can also note that $\mathbb{P}(Y=0)=0$, thus $1/Y<\infty$ almost surely and $E\left(\frac{1}{Y}\right)=E\left(\frac{1}{Y}1_{Y<\infty}\right)$, even though again, the expectation may be infinite.

As for your second question, you can write

$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(n)} \frac{1}{2} \int _0^\infty u^{n-2} e^{-u} du=\frac{1}{2(n-1)}\int _0^\infty\underbrace{\frac{1}{\Gamma(n-1)}u^{n-2} e^{-u}}_{\text{pdf of a }\Gamma(n-1,1)} du=\frac{1}{2(n-1)}.$$

You can also solve the integral by doing $n-2$ integrations by parts if you don't want to use the pdf of a $\Gamma$ distribution.

Comment: A follow up question, how to use these results to find the minimum-variance unbiased estimator (MVUE) for $\theta$?

Comment: Apply the [Lehmann–Scheffé theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmann%E2%80%93Scheff%C3%A9_theorem) to $\frac{n-1}{\sum W_i}$.

Comment: can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: Be wary that I am not a statistician, but I think this works. You proved that $W=\sum W_i$ is a sufficient statistic. You can also check that it is complete (since $W$ follows a $\Gamma$ distribution which is part of the exponential family). Additionally, you proved that $E(g(W))=\theta$, where $g:w\mapsto(n-1)/w$, i.e. $g(W)$ is an unbiased estimator of $\theta$. Hence, by the L-S theorem, $g(W)$ is the MVUE of $\theta$.

Comment: $$g(W) = \frac{(n-1)}{\sum_{i=1}^n W_i} = \frac{(n-1)}{-\sum_{i=1}^n ln(Y_i)}?$$

Comment: Yes, I am using those notations.